# I have a problem with getting data from local host in Flutter

Tags: flutter, localhost, emulation

I am using the following function to get data from localhost to the emulator
also I am using XAMPP, the function is working well with the internet but not for the local host
when I tried to use the url (I used in the function) in the emulator, it works well and it gets the data

I hope if anyone have a solution for this problem
thank you all

```
 Future GetData() async {
    Uri url = Uri.http('10.0.2.2', '/mobtech/index.php');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return responsebody;
 }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Json Test 1'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: GetData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Text(snapshot.data[i]['title'],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      );
                    });
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post the results of this API cal, what comes out in your console?

Comment: I thing the problem is inside your XAMPP server configuration, that is not allowing request from other local connection. Just to make sure, check if you are able to connect to it using another device within the local connection

Comment: Thanks for your guides but nothing appear in the console

And yes adadion, I am with you, I think it is an XAMPP problem but I don't know how to make your check

Answer (score 0):

You must put you current ip as host, here it's a example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRLSfB4r_a8ee

Comment: thank you for your answer, but actually I did as mentioned in the video, he said I should use my IP if I am using a real device but if using emulator you should use the IP 10.0.2.2

Comment: same at me too.I tested dio: ^3.0.10.This is fine but i upgraded to latest version.Don't get response.I don't know what error and nothing show error message.